# Поддержка запятой в поле ввода PHP

Tags: php, функции, input

Всем привет.
В поле ввода приложения в том виде, в каком оно существует сейчас, можно вводить только вещественные числа в формате PHP, т.е. с плавающей точкой.
Вопрос: Как сделать так, чтобы выражения вычислялись и при вводе обычной запятой?
Есть функция str_replace,  но как её применить не могу разобраться.
Заранее благодарю за ответ!
Код прилагаю.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Конвертор</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Преобразование из дюймов в сантиметры</h1>
        <form action="convertor3.php" method="post">
            <p>Величина в дюймах:
            <input type="text" name="inches" size="10"></p>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Преобразовать"></p>
        </form>
        <?php
        if (isset($_POST['inches'])) {
            $ins = (double)$_POST['inches'];
            if ($ins > 0) {
            $cents = round($ins * 2.54);
            echo '<p>', $ins, ' дюймов = ', $cents, ' сантиметров. </p>';
        }  else
        echo '<h3> Величина в дюймах должна быть больше Нуля! </h3>';
    }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: str_replace(что заменять, на что заменять, где заменять) --- str_replace(',','.',$_POST['inches'])

Comment: Премного благодарен!!!!